# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, feature-request, announcements, election

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that use the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.

[Click here to see all the information](http://se.awio.com/election.html).

The information presented is:

What the candidate wrote when nominating themselves.

- Answers/Questions on the main site and it's meta
- Up-vote/down-vote ratio
- Average reputation earned per post
- Average reputation earned per day.
- Participation in other Stack Exchange sites.

It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.

The information is presented as is with no commentary.

It came about from this question on MSO [Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75454/59303)

Comment: The GIS election doesn't appear to be listed there yet :-(.

Comment: @whuber - I just spotted that the election was on (not a regular here). I've posted the same question on other site having elections - it can take a while for the page to update. If it hasn't updated in 24 hours, ping me again and I'll see if I can contact Yi.

Comment: Thanks, @Chris.

Comment: We still haven't shown up, @Chris.

Comment: Apparently there's a place to post bugs/requests on the app here: http://stackapps.com/questions/2049/stack-exchange-elections-statistics-page/2357#2357

Comment: GIS has been added (you may need to clear browser cache and reload)